# Alternatives to Hurewicz Theorem for non-simply connected spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question

For a topological space $X$, the Hurewicz Theorem relates the homology groups of $X$ with its homotopy groups. However, for non-simply connected spaces the Hurewicz theorem doesn't say much. I'd like to know if there are other theorems relating the homology and homotopy groups of a topological space even if the relation is very weak.

Comment: My article on "Modelling and Computing Homotopy Types:I" uses some nonabelian methods: it  is available freely from Elsevier to anyone clicking on the link https://authors.elsevier.com/a/1WGM64PiHtGJi before Feb 10, 2018.  It does not quite do what the last sentence of your question asks for. But it does, I believe, raise related issues, which, as explained there, go back to the early 20th century:e.g.,  how to get higher versions of the nonabelian fundamental group?

Answer (score 1):

After the Hurewicz theorem, I'd say the next result along those lines deals with minimal models in rational homotopy theory. It still works best in the simply-connected (or at least nilpotent case), but the results are stronger. The basic idea is that we can construct a certain graded differential $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra $A_{PL}(X)$, the Sullivan minimal model, from the space $X$; and then we can read off the rational homotopy groups $\pi_*(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ from it. (In a rough sense, $A_{PL}(X)$ is the smallest graded differential algebra whose cohomology is just $H^*(X, \mathbb{Q})$.) This leads to a very quick computation of the rational homotopy groups of $S^n$, for example, since its cohomology is so simple; and because the (integral) homotopy groups of $S^n$ are ridiculously complicated, this result is about the best that can be expected. The details of the construction of $A_{PL}(X)$ can get a bit involved, but Felix, Halperin, and Thomas' "Rational Homotopy Theory" goes into the details (and is a very well-written book).

Answer (score 1):

Not directly with homology, but with cohomology. There are natural bijections $T: \langle X,K(G,n)\rangle \to H^n(X,G)$ for all CW-complexes $X$ and all $n>0$, with $G$ being an abelian group and $\langle X,K(G,n)\rangle$ are the basepoint preserving homotopy classes of maps. $T([f])=f*(\alpha)$ where $\alpha\in H^n(K(G,n),G)$ is a certain class. And now you know how to relate homology with cohomology, i.e. by Universal Coefficient theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem). This fundamental fact plays very important role in obstruction theory as well. For more details, see Hatcher, section $4.3$.